# Деплой war в Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven, tomcat

Есть веб приложение(SpringMVC + SpringSecurity + Bootstrap + mySQL). В iDea с интегрированным Tomcat7 всё работает прекрасно. Всё сделано на аннотациях, web.xml отсутствует, чтобы не было ошибки при сборке, в pom.xml прописал:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
   <configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Делаю сборку Maven clean+package, получаю Nice-1.0.war. Скидываю этот war в папку webapps не интегрированного Tomcat7, жму start service, архив распаковывается. В браузере перехожу по ссылке localhost:8080/Nice-1.0, получаю месседж /Nice-1.0/WEB-INF/pages/start.jsp и дескрипшн The requested resource is not available. Как с этим бороться?

В @Configuration классе прописан бин:

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver()
 resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
 resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
 resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
 resolver.setOrder(1);
 return resolver;
}
```

Структура проекта в iDea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура собранного Maven'ом war'ника

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вкладка artifacts в iDea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код контролёра

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String readdressingLogin() {
        return "login";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String start() {
        return "start";
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, что кто-то неправильно задал структуру исходников прожекта для веб-приложения под управлением мавена.
Обычно выглядит так (опуская лишнее):

```
src
 `- main
      `- java
           `- тут исходники java
      `- resources
      `- webapp
           `- WEB-INF
           `- pages
                `- page.jsp
           `- css
           `- img
           `- js
           `- index.jsp
```

Структура war должна получиться такой:

```
Nice
  `- WEB-INF
        `- classes - скомпилированные классы и всякая фигня из resources
        `- lib - библиотеки jar
  `- pages
       `- page.jsp
  `- css
  `- img
  `- js
  `- index.jsp
```

Сравните со своим

Содержимое resources располагаются в готовом war в /WEB-INF/classes и не доступно из браузера. Вы свои веб-ресурсы как раз и бросили туда, куда не следовало бы.
Это не правильно

```
src
 `- main
      `- java
           `- тут исходники java
      `- resources
           `- WEB-INF         неправильно
           `- pages           неправильно
                `- page.jsp
           `- css             неправильно
           `- img             неправильно
           `- js              неправильно
           `- index.jsp       неправильно
```

Comment: Спасибо, это верно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй запустить tomcat, перейти по ссылке [менеджера](http://localhost:8080/manager/html) и задеплоить свой `.war` через него, добавив `applixation context`.

После того как ты переместишь свои страницы в папку `web-app` - получится такая структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]

Затем тебе нужно будет переписать свой `setupViewResolver()`:

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
```

А уже после всего этого деплой через [менеджер](http://localhost:8080/manager/html) и переходи по ссылке [своего контроллера](http://localhost:8080/)

Указать путь к проекту и `application context`:

[image: deploy]

А затем получить это сообщение:

[image: message]

И получать доступ к приложению по пути `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Общая задача - развернуть приложение на хостинге, делаю первый раз, решил сначала попробовать локально наTomcat. Есть контроллёр@RequestMapping("/") в нём есть метод `@RequestMapping("/")
    public String start() {
        return "start";
    }` отправляющий на страницу, но Tomcat безуспешно ищет её по адресу - `/WEB-INF/pages/start.jsp`, т.е. по тому пути, который прописан в UrlBasedViewResolver, а если посмотреть на структуру war(см.выше), то видно что страницы(они в папке pages) лежат не там, где он их ищет. Если не так `localhost:8080/Nice-1.0`, то как правильно запустить приложение.

Comment: Попробовал перейти по ссылке `manager` и задеплоил через него, но результат тот же - месседж /Nice-1.0/WEB-INF/pages/start.jsp и дескрипшн The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Сейчас я пересмотрел структуру твоего проекта и понял в чём дело, вчера я этого не заметил. Вся проблема в том, что у тебя страницы находятся в ресурсах.
Ты должен создать в папке main папку web-app, а в ней свою папку pages

Comment: З.Ы папку resources не обязательно переносить в web-app

Comment: Просто, переименовал в проекте папку resources в webapp и пересобрал war. Теперь при переходе по ссылке `http://localhost:8080/Nice-1.0/` открывается стартовая страница приложения. Но пройти дальше по ссылке, например:`<a ... href="/login">` на самой странице нельзя - The requested resource is not available, браузер ищет ресурс по этому адресу `http://localhost:8080/login`, если в строке адреса дописать `/Nice-1.0`, чтобы получилось http://localhost:8080/Nice-1.0/login, только тогда происходит обращение к контролёру. Как сделать по-человечески?

Comment: Добавь свой контроллер в вопрос целиком

Comment: Добавил, см.выше.

Comment: Тогда я вообще не понимаю почему ты переходишь на `http://localhost:8080/Nice-1.0/`. Ведь судя по маппингу в контроллере нужно переходить по этой ссылке `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Да, но этот путь будет только в случае если запускать приложение в среде разработки кнопкой run. Переход в браузере по `http://localhost:8080/` отправляет на домашнюю страницу tomcat, переход по `http://localhost:8080/Nice-1.0/` открывает доступ к корню  Nice-1.0.war, всё что следует дальше - обращение к контролёрам(например: `http://localhost:8080/Nice-1.0/login`), т.е. если в контролёре прописать путь `/Nice-1.0/login` вместо просто `/login`, то адресная строка в браузере должна будет выглядеть так `http://localhost:8080/Nice-1.0/Nice-1.0/login`.

Comment: По-порядку: Делаю сборку Maven clean+package, получаю Nice-1.0.war.
В браузере перехожу по `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`, далее WAR file to deploy: обзор->deploy, в таблице Applications в Path появляется мой `/Nice-1.0`, перехожу по этой ссылке(см.картинку выше), далее получаю то что получаю. Никак не могу разобраться.

Comment: Так сделай ссылку на странице в таком виде `<a ... href="/Nice-1.0/login">` вместо `<a ... href="/login">`. А в контроллере не нужно дописывать ничего такого `/Nice-1.0/login`

Comment: Попробовал - сработало, но это похоже на танцы с бубном, есть ли какое-то человеческое решение? Ведь если я решу допилить приложение и Nice-1.0.war изменит версию на Nice-1.1.war, это будет необходимо учесть во всех ссылках на всех страницах(она не одна!!). По сути, просто обычное переименование war повлияет на работу всего приложения..

Comment: Я не особо понимаю почему у тебя так получается. У меня в пути никогда не было названия war файла при деплое. Просто деплоил war на сервер и получал доступ к нему по своим маппингам типа `localhost:8080/index`, если оставлял application context в виде "/"

Comment: `если оставлял application context в виде "/"` - расскажи по-подробней, пожалуйста, что и где, этот момент я, наверное, и упустил.

Comment: в менеджере tomcat у моего приложения отсутствует Display Name(см.картинку), уже не знаю имеет ли это значение. При запуске приложения в строке браузера начальный путь должен состоять из `localhost:8080/myApp`, (myApp - имя war - ссылка в таблице менеджера tomcat) и при последующих переходах по маппингам этот начальный путь сохраняется - `localhost:8080/myApp/index`, у меня же этот путь, почему-то, сбрасывается на `localhost:8080/index`

Comment: Смотри в моём ответе то, что добавил

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, переименуй файл в ROOT.war и заходи на localhost:8080. Это поможет проверить работоспособность сервера в целом.

Comment: В папке webapps есть папка с именем ROOT, после переименования war в ROOT.war архив не распаковывался, после удаления архива исчезла и папка ROOT. Переустановил Tomcat.